# java- iCal4j - Adding description of a meeting

Tags: java, ical4j

I am using `iCal4j` to creating ics file from outlook calendar. Now when I am creating a VEvent object, I am adding the calendar subject.

```
VEvent meeting = new VEvent(startDate, endDate, subject);
```

But how to add the meeting description ? I could not find any option to add it. Any suggestion will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to do it through the properties list; for example

```
VEvent meeting = new VEvent(startDate, endDate, subject);
meeting.getProperties().add(new Description("Description text goes here"));
```